# Laravel: Get single model using pivot table with where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got 3 tables:

- Car: belongsToMany Owner
- Owner: belongsToMany Car
- CarOwner: pivot table for Car and Owner with an additional column 'active' that indicates who is the current Owner of a Car

So a Car might have multiple or no Owners and vica versa BUT a Car has only 1 current ('active') Owner.

```js
class Car extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function owners()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Owner::class, 'car_owners');
    }

    public function currentOwner()
    {
        return $this->owners()->where('active', true)->first();
    }
}
```

My problem is if a Car has no active Owner, Laravel throws the following exception when I want to use `$car->currentOwner` in a `Blade` template:

`App\Models\Car::currentOwner must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used?`

How can I handle if a Car doesn't have any active Owners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute instead of a relation function:

```
    public function getCurrentOwnerAttribute()
    {
        return $this->owners()->where('active', true)->first();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the same line in my `currentOwner()` function. :)

Comment: @flow3r your function is different. by using "public function currentOwner()" you set a relation,  "public function getCurrentOwnerAttribute()" creates a custom attribute. that you can call by using $car->currentOwner. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know the difference between our function declarations, I'm new to Laravel. But your solution works, thanks!